# How to get substring from the given string?

Tags: java, string

I have read whole xml file as single string using class.The output is

```
String result=<?xml version="1.0"?><catalog><book id="bk101"><part1><date>Fri Apr 05 11:46:46 IST 2013</date><author>Gambardella, Matthew</author><title>XML Developer's Guide</title><genre>Computer</genre><price>44.95</price>         <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date></part1></book></catalog>
```

Now i want to replace date value.so first i want to extract date from the string and replace new value.I have following code,

```
  Date date=new Date()
  String str=result.substring(result.indexOf("<date>"));
```

It displays whole string from date tag to end tag.
How to extract date tag and replace it?

Comment: Why not use the built in XML parsing API?

Comment: String str=result.substring(result.indexOf("<date>"),result.indexOf("</date>"));

Comment: You can use regular expression

Comment: Hi @RongNK, I'm going to say just because you're new here. If you ever advise people to use regular expression to parse XML or HTML than the wrath of StackOverflow will descend upon your head. It is almost never the correct way to do it.

Comment: Thank Joe, i will  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just the value:

```
String str = result.substring(result.indexOf("<date>") + "<date>".length(),
        result.indexOf("</date>"));
```

Including the tags:

```
String str = result.substring(result.indexOf("<date>"),
        result.indexOf("</date>") + "</date>".length());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String str=result.substring(result.indexOf("<date>") ,result.indexOf("</date>")+"</date>".length());
```

[String#substring(int beginIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29)

> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring
>   begins with the character at the specified index and extends to the
>   end of this string.

String#substring(int beginIndex,int endIndex)

> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring
>   begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at
>   index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is
>   endIndex-beginIndex.

Comment: thanks but it display <date>Fri Apr 05 11:46:46 IST 2013< .I think need to extract as <date>Fri Apr 05 11:46:46 IST 2013</date> this format.

Answer (score 1):

This here gets the contents of the  tags using regex... but as for replacing it - I'll get back to you.

```
String result = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><catalog><book id=\"bk101\"><part1><date>Fri Apr 05 11:46:46 IST 2013</date><author>Gambardella, Matthew</author><title>XML Developer's Guide</title><genre>Computer</genre><price>44.95</price>         <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date></part1></book></catalog>";
String pattern = ".*(?i)(<date.*?>)(.+?)(</date>).*";
System.out.println(result.replaceAll(pattern, "$2"));
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Oh, you wanted it in java. This is the C# solution =)

You can solve this by replacing the entire date including the  tag.

You have two dates in your XML so to be sure that you will not replace both of them you can do it like this.

```
int index1 = result.IndexOf("<date>");
int index2 = result.IndexOf("</date>") - index1 + "</date>".Length;
var stringToReplace = result.Substring(index1, index2);

var newResult = result.Replace(stringToReplace, "<date>" + "The Date that you want to insert" + "</date>");
```